# Created a Spring boot app with rest based and data source inside STS plugin in eclipse - but getting illegalstateexception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Had Installed STS plugin inside eclipse and Created a spring boot application from it with rest and database support. And I currently am yet to start using the DB support. I just want to test the rest app first and then implement DB read.

I have the following files:

OpsbldSvcApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OpsbldSvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OpsbldSvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

OpsbldParamsController.java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

    public class OpsbldParamsController {

        private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
        private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
            return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                String.format(template, name));
        }
    }
```

Greeting.java:

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

And also have the following valid config in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=<snipped>
spring.datasource.username=<snipped>
spring.datasource.password=<snipped>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

But getting the following exception when running "mvnw.cmd package" :

> 2018-07-04 12:33:16.853 ERROR 7508 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplicat ion               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean wit h name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/aut
>   oconfigure/jdbc/XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via fac tory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiat ionException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'data Source' threw
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Un
>   able to create XADataSource instance from
>   'oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSou rce'

Could someone identify what am I missing.. what I should I do to get it working ?

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your data source. Do you have the database, drivers and access to the DB? Is the URL correct for the DB?

Comment: yes.. they are correct.. I can connect to them using standard DB client apps